# How to get Django form method to not 500 when debug is false on raising a form error?

Tags: django, forms

I have the following code for my login:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length = 254, min_length = 6)
    password = forms.CharField(min_length = 8, widget = forms.PasswordInput())

    def Login(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(email = email, password = password)

        if (user is None) or (user is not None and user.is_active is False):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Login is incorrect.')

        return user
```

However when I have debug set to false on my site, whenever the login is incorrect I get a 500 error instead of the form displaying the ValidationError. I am calling it like:

```
if form.is_valid():
    user = form.Login()
```

That is in a view method. What am I missing here? How do I properly call this form error so it doesn't 500 when debug is set to false?

Comment: should `Login` not be called `def clean` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django. Error message for login form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084597/django-error-message-for-login-form)

Comment: Hi, you are right and my solution was in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084597/django-error-message-for-login-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call like this

```
def clean(self):
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')   
    user = authenticate(email = email, password = password)
    if (user is None) or (user is not None and user.is_active is False):
        raise forms.ValidationError('Login is incorrect.')
    return self.cleaned_data

def login(self,request):
    user = authenticate(email = self.cleaned_data.get('email'),password = self.cleaned_data.get('password'))
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    return user
```